# Bayes- Poisson distribution. MLE, prior and posterior analysis in R

Tags: r

I am new to this website and also I am putting first steps in R.

I have found the similar code (for binominal distribution) on github and was trying to apply in into poisson distribution. the result is... ehh.. :/
can anyone help me make the plots appear? What is wrong?

All I need is the plot having prior, posterior and maximum likelihood. 
I was also trying to use dgamma (x, a, b) but the result was unexpected..

```
GammaPriorPostPlot <- function(a,b,n,p){
    standarizedLikelihood = dgamma(dane2, n*p+1, n*(1-p)+1)
    prior = dgamma(dane2, a, b)
    posterior = dgamma(dane2, a+n*p, b+n*(1-p))
    maxDensity <- max(standarizedLikelihood, prior, posterior) # Use to make the y-axis high enough
    plot(dane2, standarizedLikelihood, type = 'l', lwd = 3, col = "blue", xlim <- c(0,1), ylim <- c(0, maxDensity), xlab = "theta", 
            ylab = 'density', main = 'Gamma(a,b)')
    lines(dane2, posterior, lwd = 3, col = "red")
    lines(dane2, prior, lwd = 3, col = "green")
    legend(x = 0.01, 
              y = maxDensity*0.95, 
              legend = c("likelihood", "Prior",  "Posterior"), 
              col = c("blue","green","red"), 
              lwd = c(3,3,3), cex = 0.7)
}

 manipulate(GammaPriorPostPlot(a,b,n,p),
            a = slider(1, 100, step=1, initial = 100, label = "a"),
            b = slider(1, 100, step=1, initial = 2, label = "b"),
            n = slider(1, 1000, step=1, initial = 10, label = "num of observations"),
            p = slider(0, 1, step=0.01, initial = 0.4, label = "success probability")
```

My data is this:

rok t   l.kobiet
2002    1   51
2003    2   45
2004    3   41
2005    4   46
2006    5   44
2007    6   67
2008    7   81
2009    8   63
2010    9   61
2011    10  44
2012    11  59
2013    12  48

I took only the third column for my data (number of women, l.kobiet)

Comment: `the result is... ehh.. :/` Please be more specific. Does it give an error? Does it show no plots?

Comment: What's dane2? ... and what package are you assuming we have loaded when you call `manipulate`?

Comment: unfortunately it is showing just a blank plot with legend, with no lines of MLE, Prior nor posterior.  Even when i manipulate the sliders, the lines in the plot do not appear.

Comment: right, it is manipulate package. dane2 is a vector of data from the third column (number of women)

Comment: `> range(dane2[[3]]) #[1] 41 81`  but the xlim is c(0,1), furthermore using "<-" in parameter assignment will fail in many instances. Probably need to sort the dane2 argument or you will get lines going in all directions.